# How can i modify AltGr with xmodmap?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

Hi i have a little problem with the order of two keys in my keyboard, instead of being <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>< ></kbd> like in most of the keyboards in my country, my keyboard comes with the keys this way: <kbd>< ></kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>. Where each par of brackets represents a key.

To fix it i swapped the physic keys and created a file called `.xmodmaprc` in my home directory and put this on it:

```
keycode 94 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift

keycode 108 = less greater
```

Then i run this command: `sudo xmodmap ~/.xmodmaprc`

After running the command i get the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key working okey but i have a problem with the <kbd>< ></kbd> key, when i press it i get `<` like  it should be but when i press shift <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>< ></kbd> i get `<` instead of `>`.

Do someone know how to fix this?